# Selenium Python Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I'm trying to gather price information for each product variation from this web page: https://www.safetysign.com/products/7337/ez-pipe-marker

I'm using Selenium and FireFox with Python 3 and Windows 10.

Here is my current code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.safetysign.com/products/7337/ez-pipe-marker')
#frame = driver.find_element_by_class_name('product-dual-holder')
# driver.switch_to.frame('skuer5c866ddb91611')
# driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('skuer5c866ddb91611-size-label-324').click()   
price = driver.find_element_by_class_name("product-pricingnodecontent product-price-content").text.replace('$', '')
products.at[counter, 'safetysign.com Price'] = price
print(price)
print(products['safetysign.com URL'].count()-counter)
```

So, I'm trying to start by just selecting the first product variation by id (I've also tried class name). But, I get an Unable to locate element error. As suggested in numerous SO posts, I tried to change frames (even though I can't find a frame tag in the html that contains this element). I tried switching to different frames using index, class name, and id of different div elements that I thought might be a frame, but none of this worked. I also tried using waits, but that return the same error.

Any idea what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Which element - name it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They may well be dynamic. Select by `label` type selector instead and index to click on required item e.g. 0 for the item you mention (first in the list). Also, add a wait condition for `label`s to be present.

If you want to limit to just those 5 `size` choices then use the following css selector instead of `label` :

```
.sku-contents ul:nth-child(3) label
```

i.e.

```
sizes = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sku-contents ul:nth-child(3) label")))
sizes[0].click()
```

After selecting size you can grab the price from the price node depending on whether you want the price for a given sample size e.g. 0-99.

To get final price use:

```
.product-under-sku-total-label
```

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
url = 'https://www.safetysign.com/products/7337/ez-pipe-marker'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
labels = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label")))
labels[0].click()
price0to99 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.product-pricingnodecontent').text
priceTotal = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.product-under-sku-total-label').text
print(priceTotal, price0To99)
# driver.quit()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! This works for getting the different sizes, but I can't access the price for each size. I think it is the same issue I had with accessing the sizes (they seem to be dynamic), so I tried using the CSS_SELECTOR approach, but get a timeoutexception error. For the price, I used "price = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id=skuer5c866ddb91611-total-price]")))" I've never used CSS selector before, so I'm pretty sure I just doing it wrong.

Comment: use .product-pricingnodecontent I have updated answer for you to show price for 0-99 etc.... use .product-under-sku-total-label  for total.

Comment: Any problems let me know.

Comment: While the answer answers seem to work (or will work if I were to adjust a few things, I, I went with this answer because it seemed the cleanest to me. Thanks @QHarr!

Answer (score 1):

To locate the elements you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can create a *List* and iterate over it to `click()` each item and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


  driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.safetysign.com/products/7337/ez-pipe-marker")
  for product in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//form[@class='product-page-form']//div[@class='sku-contents']//following::ul[1]/li//label[starts-with(@for, 'skuer') and contains(., 'Pipe')]"))):
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of(product)).click()
  driver.quit()
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have two problems. One, I'm using Firefox and can't figure out how to set the same options as you have done for Chrome. Second, when I run the code without those options, I get a TimeoutException error that just reads 'Message: '

Comment: @JarodJacobs Check out the updated answer and let me know the status.